# My IDE doesn't accept code that worked a month ago?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

The only thing i have changed is downloaded pygame on my mac via the terminal.
When i type the follwing code -

```
name = input("what is your name?")
print ("Hello", name)
```

into my IDE i get this in the terminal -

> what is your name? Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mikeyboy/PycharmProjects/untitled11/waht.py", line 1, in
>   
>       name = input("what is your name?")   File "", line 0
>
> ```
> ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
> ```
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What's gone wrong this code worked perfectly a month ago?

Comment: Try doing ctrl + alt + shift + l in linux or windows, to reformat the code, save the file and try to rerun it...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting 
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
instead of ...
    name = input("What is your name?")

Anybody know why the latter worked before and now it doesn't?

Comment: `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3. It seems your IDE is using Python 3 and your code was written for python 2.

Comment: However, that wouldn't give you a `SyntaxError`, so maybe there was some strange formatting somewhere that got fixed when you edited the file.